# Remote desktop printer sharing

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, printer, remote

I have two computers both running Windows 7 Professional x64. One computer has a USB printer connected (Dell V715W) which is working properly. When I create a RDP connection from the PC with the printer to the other PC, the printer is not shared.

In the RDP settings I selected to share the printer in Local Resources, but no printer is visible.

Comment: 2 items for anyone looking at this old post: Have you installed the driver on the remote machine? Do that first. If it is still not seen: Could you look at the properties of the printer on the system with the printer actually installed? What port is it on? Is it something other than a COM, LPT, or USB? If so, RDP doesn't always like it. You can get around this by enabling printer pooling on that printer and selecting LPT1 as well as the current port for example.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting via RDP click the drop arrow "options" and select the tab Local Resources click the printers check box.

[image]

Comment: I have enabled that, the problem is that the printer is not visible.

Comment: do you have the printer shared over the network?  I got confused and though you were talking about the remote PC having the printer

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you mean by "shared".

Say that computer A is with printer. It does RDP to computer B specifying the printer in local resources. Then the printer is available on computer B, but **only** for this RDP session.

RDP is not a means of sharing resources, just of bringing over your local resources during the session for your own use. And even then you might have problems if computer B doesn't have the right printer driver installed.

For sharing printers over the network, see the following article:
[Share a Printer on Your Home Network](http://lifehacker.com/309015/share-a-printer-on-your-home-network)

Or if you are using HomeGroup see:
[Use the Homegroup Feature in Windows 7 to Share Printers and Files](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-in-windows-7-with-homegroup/)

Comment: Yes that is what I mean with sharing, perhaps I picked the wrong word.

Comment: I have added more info.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to enabling the Printers option in the RDP setting, you also need to install the printer driver on the computer you are connecting to.  Once you do that, you can select the printer for printing.

Alternatively, you can enable a HomeGroup in Windows 7 that will allow you to share printers between any computers connected to your local network.  This would eliminate the need to select the Printers option in the RDP settings.

Comment: See http://www.proposedsolution.com/solutions/remote-desktop-connection-rdc-printer-install/ for some instructions on how to install the printer.